# Stack vs. Queue Brainteaser

Tags: infinity

So I have a thought in my head I was wondering if anyone could offer wisdom on, and excuse me if this is a silly question or is not philosophical in nature. The question is basically this:

Let's assume you have an infinite stream of data that you need to process, and you're wondering if it's best to use a stack or a queue when it comes to prioritizing data to process. Let's also say that the amount of time it takes to process a piece of data is longer than the amount of time it takes to receive new data from the stream. In the stack model, any new piece of data that comes in will get immediately moved to the top of the stack.

In a queue, where first come is first served, you could theoretically say that you'll get to processing every piece of data that comes in. Just take the a piece of data's place in the queue, multiply it by the amount of time it takes to process one piece of data, and that's how long it will take until you can start processing that particular piece of data in the queue.

However, in a stack, where it's first come last served, you will never actually get to every piece of data. By the time you're done processing some piece of data that's at the top, you're now processing a piece of data that is newer than the one you just finished processed.

How is it possible that with the same dataset (albeit an infinite one), one data structure can ensure you will process every piece of data (eventually), wheres in the other one you cannot?

Comment: One cannot process every piece of data in either context; the rate of incoming data ensures that the unprocessed data pool is always growing. The only difference between these methods is that a queue minimizes average wait time, while a stack guarantees that the newer data is processed before older data. You've fooled yourself into thinking that linear processing (eventually) candles all cases, but you've set up an ever-growing traffic jam scenario in which the wait time for any given data tends towards infinity.

Comment: @TedWrigley That sounds like an answer, except I am not sure average wait time is different between the two. In stack, everyones wait time is ether infinite, or almost 0. In queue there is as you said a calculable wait time that is longer for each and tends toward infinite.  I would need to dust off the mathematics Part of my brain to calculate if those are equal,  and it is late where I live.

Comment: @Damila: Averages with infinitudes are a pain, unless you *like* solving limits. But I think we can take a shortcut and model them both as a random selection (a queue is a special case where we 'randomly' pick elements in sequence; a stack is a special case where we 'randomly' pick the most recent addition). Then we can see that the wait-time would be inversely related to the probability of being chosen, which would go to zero as the number of data entries goes to infinity. Thus the expected wait time for *every* data point is infinite.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: Policy and mechanisms of data structures and abstract data types are better off in [SE Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to start by sketching an example of the workings of the stack.

Let's take a simple base case.  Assume the information stream is the integers in order. Let's also assume that each "cycle" of time it takes one thing to process, exactly two things come in. We'll call this a handling period of 2 ticks, compared to a data period of 1 tick (or handling frequency of 1/2, compared to a data frequency of 1).

So the process feed looks like this.  "1" comes in, so we process it in two ticks.  In the meantime, "2" and "3" come in in one tick intervals, and are sequentially put on top of the stack.  So two ticks after first receiving "1", our processor is free, reads the stack, and retrieves "3". Over the course of the next two ticks, our processor processes "3", but "4" and "5" are added in one tick intervals to the stack. Our processor finishes, reads "5" from the stack for processing, and so we continue on.

This is clearly a process that is creating an ever expanding stack of even numbers, and we'll never get to process "2" at the bottom of the stack if the sequence continues infinitely.  That is to say, there is no integer such that we could guarantee that "2" would be processed in that length of time.

The same is not true for your queue model.  Given any integer "n", we can prove that there is an integer length of time within which we might expect to process "n" - namely, 2n ticks!  We cannot prove that *the entire sequence* will ever complete, but we can prove that for any given element of that sequence, there is a length of time within which we will process that element.

This, I think, is the philosophically interesting distinction in your question: Given that the queue structure is a strategy within which we can define a finite time for any given integer processing to happen, why can we still not say that we will capture every single element of the series?

Well, in answer to that question, look at the cardinality and Value of the set of outputs within a given time for the Stack versus the Queue.  The outputs of both systems are in perfect 1:1 correlation, so they are solving the same number of values as each other.  And yet, what the top of the stack shows us is that at a time t, there is always going to be an integer that is coming downstream that the Queue system hasn't processed yet. If the queue is currently looking at the integer n, then the top of the stack is *the n'th even number*, which is still an integer and which the queue hasn't yet passed to the front!

It's all fine and good to say that for any given integer n we can prove that we will deal with it in 2n ticks, but we can also say that for that same integer, we know that there are at least n more elements for us to process; completely uncontroversially so, even, because there's one sitting on top of the stack as a result of a well-defined process.  So at no point in time can we say we're done, because there's *definitely* always more to do.

This is what the philosopher [Michael Dummett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Dummett) called the intuition of Indefinite Extensibility.  It seems totally reasonable for us to say that we can capture the length of time taken to process any given integer in your queue model, but also correct to say that there is still somehow more that we need to do without ever stepping outside the bounds of our set of integers.  While classical Set theory recognizes that the integers themselves are a perfectly legitimate set (thanks to the axiom of infinity), other philosophers of mathematics have made sense of this intuition using Set theoretic technology to apply it to more complex notions than this particular sketch; for example, the class of all Ordinal numbers (including the transfinite ones) seems to make sense, but cannot be treated as a set on pain of paradox.  Indefinite Extensibility suggests a way to conceptualize a distinction between sets and proper classes.

Dummett wanted to use this concept to demonstrate that certain kinds of mathematical practice were not suited to reasoning using classical logic.  To do this, he pointed out that there were indeed some well-defined mathematical concepts (mostly transfinite) that nonetheless lacked the potential to be rolled out into a well-defined extensional treatment suitable for classical quantification.  This was a reason to consider alternative logical treatments, such as those forms of semantics grounded in proofs rather than abstract truth.

This position has been quite influential in the drive to develop systems like theorem provers and natural deduction/sequent calculus models for reasoning about logical statements and computer programs. If this kind of stuff interests you, there's definitely plenty to read on!

Comment: What an awesome answer! I really appreciate the thorough explanation